# How to not replicate an paragraph on tbs:page

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I have a template with one page containing a block of `tbs:page` type. This function replicate greatly my content.

But i have a problem. On top of this page, I have a `title/topic` for my table of contents, but i only need this index on the first page of this replication. How to do this?

I tried before `block=begin` with the end. But this doesn't work for me because of the white page on the end! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a magnet field that will delete the title paragraph when the record number is 1.

Here is the TBS field, assuming your block is named « b » :

```
[b.#;magnet=tbs:p;ope=mko:1]
```

Explanations :

- `#` is a spacial key that display the record number (first is 1). So [b.#] will display 1, 2, 3, ...
- `magnet=tbs:p` makes the field linked to the paragraph that surround it.
- `ope=mko:1` will delete the magnet when value is `1`.

Comment: Thank you Skrol29, i'll try this, but i'll do this on inverse what you explain, because this title need to show only on first page of replication! Soon i'll back here for feedback! Thanks

Comment: @MarcosFerreira then replace `ope=mko:1` with `ope=mok:1`